# Lighting a SpriteKit SKEmitterNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have a SpriteKit game in which there's an `SKEmitterNode`.

In the process of lighting the scene with an `SKLightNode`, I noticed that `SKEmitterNode` does not have the `lightingBitMask` property required for lighting. An `SKSpriteNode`, for example, is lighting-enabled like this:

```
spriteNode.lightingBitMask = 0b0001
```

The emitter particles are visible in the dark, which is undesirable. Instead, I'd like the particles to obey the light/dark difference.

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve this lighting effect with `SKEmitterNode` and `SKLightNode`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make the SKEmitterNode a child of some SKSpriteNode (just 2x2 pixels).
Then you can modify the lightingBitMask of this parent SKSpriteNode.